# @RequestMapping can't catch url

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, servlets, controller

I declare controller with a form. But when I use Delete url, catch 404 Error

I have a table with code:

```
<c:forEach items="${model.books}" var="book">
        <tr align="left" height="100%">
            <td>${book.name}</td>
            <td>${book.description}</td>
            <td>${book.year}</td>
            <td></td>
                <%--<td>${book.authorNames}</td>--%>
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <td>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/BookList.vw/${book.id}">Delete</a>
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/EditBook.vw/${book.id}">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </sec:authorize>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BookList.vw")
public class BookListController {

    @Autowired
    private IBookService bookService;

    public String getModelName() {
        return "BookList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView openMain() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Book> books = bookService.listBooks();
        model.put("books", books);

        return new ModelAndView(getModelName(), "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/delete"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView delete(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) throws Exception {
        bookService.removeBook(id);
        return new ModelAndView(getModelName());
    }
}
```

By second URL I catch 404 Error too. I don't understand why.
EditBook controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/EditBook.vw")
public class EditBookController{

    @Autowired
    private IBookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private IAuthorService authorService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView openMain(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Book> books = bookService.listBooks();
        Book book = new Book();
        for (Book book1 : books) {
            if(book1.getId() == id)
                book = book1;
        }

        model.put("book", book);

        return new ModelAndView("EditBook", "model", model);
    }
}
```

I try to change it on POST, Get and other between.. Help me? please

Answer (score 1):

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {
        bookService.removeBook(id);
        return new ModelAndView(getModelName());
    }
```

Can you try this?

Comment: can you please go over this [thread ] (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/76651-problem-with-requestmapping-and-pathvariable) and if not found a solution, share your servletcontex.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your controller declared that only post request will execute delete() method. You should use a

```
<form method="post" action="the_delete_URL">
```

instead of 
     
because href ain't a post.

Comment: U need to use form post and not href, try acemerk's method again but use method = RequestMethod.POST ? In the stack trace you pasted clearly state its a @PathVariable not found error.